# SpriteKit Layer Scratch Effect

Tags: ios7, core-graphics, sprite-kit

I am creating a game in SpriteKit in which I have some SKShapeNodes. I want the SKShapeNodes to be hidden by color. For example:

1. initially as the scene loads, it should show as plain color.
2. The user scratches (touches and moves touch) to scratch the color and reveals the shapes behind the color. I will perform other actions on these shapes later

If any one suggests this link:
https://github.com/moqod/iOS-Scratch-n-See

then I have already gone from this but the problem is this that it is using two images one as front and other as background and it is in core graphics. I am completely beginner to core graphics and having difficulty to understand how to show color instead of image to scratch.

I understand that the question has been already asked but it is using images. I want to have only one color as layer which will be scratched.

Any one will please help me how to achieve scratch effect to scratch color and reveal other nodes behind?